# Extra services Push notification, data access and data storage, what does it mean?

Tags: windows-10, virus

I just see in my task manager, "Services" tab, some entries I don't understand, as you can see here:

```
UnistoreSvc          User Data Storage                             Stopped UnistackSvcGroup    => Ok
UnistoreSvc_7f570    User Data Storage_7f570                       Stopped UnistackSvcGroup    => ???
UserDataSvc          User Data Access                              Stopped UnistackSvcGroup    => Ok
UserDataSvc_7f570    User Data Access_7f570                        Stopped UnistackSvcGroup    => ???
WpnUserService       Windows Push Notification User Service        Stopped UnistackSvcGroup    => Ok
WpnUserService_7f570 Windows Push Notification User Service_7f570  Running UnistackSvcGroup    => ???
```

I'm especially worried about the apparently auto-generated name of the feature, and the fact that it seems to replace the previously installed Windows Push Notification User Service.

The process uses the basic `svchost.exe` program, I have no idea how to proceed.

Does anybody know what this is and if it might be a virus? (I have an virusscanner on my PC, but you never know if it covers all possible risks)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is User Data Access\_14d4fe service and how can I get rid of it?](https://superuser.com/questions/1130455/what-is-user-data-access-14d4fe-service-and-how-can-i-get-rid-of-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is some Windows services you don't wanna mess up with.

The User Data Storage (`UnistoreSvc`) / User Data Access (`UserDataSvc`), as [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1130967/880618) says:

> Allows apps access user data, including contact info, calendars, messages, and other content. Apps need such a service because apps run in a sandbox and can't access the data the way like desktop applications would do it.

The Windows Push Notification User Service, [documented](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/windows-push-notification-services--wns--overview) in Microsoft, is:

> It's a service that enables third-party developers to send toast, tile, badge, and raw updates from their own cloud service. This provides a mechanism to deliver new updates to your users in a power-efficient and dependable way.